# Seeking Expert Advice for Banff Trip: Upgrade Dilemma - New

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, portrait, landscape

I'm gearing up for a trip to Banff, Alberta, next year. Planning to go for a week and see both Banff and Jasper. I need some expert advice on lenses. Currently, I'm using a Canon RP with a RF 15-35mm 2.8 + EF 50mm 1.8 lens. My main focus is to take landscape photography of the Rockies with a little bit of portrait shots of friends and family in the foreground.

Now, here's where I need some insights - I'm torn between expanding my lens collection with a 24-70mm and/or a 70-200mm or considering adding just one of those lenses along with a new camera body like the R8 or R5. What would you recommend? Should I go for the versatility of an additional lens and a new camera body or stick with 1 or 2 lens upgrade? Let me know your thoughts and experiences!

Comment: In what ways are you limited by your current equipment? If you can answer that, you'll know what to buy. If you can't answer that, the best idea is probably not to buy anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no right or wrong answer to your question... it's just opinion. And a lot depends on how you will actually use the pictures.

Comment: Similar question: [What do you take on a hike as a landscape photographer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38526),

Comment: Related: [Will I see enough improvement moving from EF-S to "L" lenses to warrant the cost?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/81925/15871) and [Will a lens upgrade from the kit lens give me better colors on my backpacking travels?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/95230/15871) The idea of upgrading gear for a "trip of a lifetime" is well intentioned, but rarely makes near as much difference as the buyer expects. Good photographs are more about light (it's ALWAYS mostly about the light), composition, shooting technique, and processing than about lenses and camera bodies.

Comment: What do you expect an R8/R5 to allow you to do that you can't do with your RP? What do you expect a 24-70/2.8 or 70-200 to allow you to do that your current lenses don't? Obviously, you have no lenses longer than 50mm at present. But what photos do you wish to take that need a 70-200mm? Or a 24-70mm? If you can't answer these questions, the newer gear probably won't make much of a difference. Save your money and spend a few more days on your trip instead.

Comment: Been to both, and well worth the trip. Consider if you'll be hiking: there are many day hikes and longer, from a short walk up Tunnel Mountain overlooking Banff, to Verdant Pass on Mt. Edith Cavell and the 44 km Skyline Trail in Jasper. Also consider if you'll be on rivers or lakes. How much can you carry? Is it weather sealed? Do you need a waterproof case?